# Replace \" in a csv column java

Tags: java, string, csv, replace

I have a json as csv file column value. I am using csv reader for processing the file. The problem is while parsing this particular string

```
"status": false,
"name": "\"funaction(Group, ind and six)",
"id": "groupindsix"
```

As there is a \" , the **csv reader escapes the second line** as

"name": "funaction(Group, ind and six)

Hence the comma which is supposed to be inside the double quote separates into a different column with "ind and six" in separate column.

I need a way to replace the \" only in the string. I tried `replace("\\\","")` but no use. Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the first quote. By using `\"`, you escape the quotation mark and prevent it from being used as a quote closer. You need to add an extra quotation mark as in

```
replace("\\\"","")
```

Comment: Sorry missed the quote in question. I have done that way only.. but its not replacing the only \" . it replaces the end double quote also after six)"/